# How to Publish or Deploy Xamarin android app to my phone samsung galaxy s3

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin Andriod. I have done one simple application (Hello world on button click) in VS 2012 after installing xamarin studio and tested it in emulator (for the AVD created similar to Samsung Galaxy S3). Can anyone Please tell me the steps to move this application (.apk) file to S3 phone and run it on S3 phone.

Comment: http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42

Comment: Have you looked at the Xamarin documentation?  The steps are clearly described.  You need to set your device for development: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/ and then, you can deploy your app for debugging http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_with_xamarin_android/

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in 2 ways.

1. Connect your phone to PC using USB Cable. If succesfully connected, you will find your device in emulators list. Select your device and Run. Application will launch on your device.
2. Other way is to manually create a .apk and and copy that file on to device and install it. This method is lot time consuming and not suitable for development purpose. 
   Details at : http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

Comment: 1) is actually what I did and works greats, provided that you activate the "developper" mode on you device. Once done, nothing to do to get your device detected and listed on VS.

Comment: Thank for sharing...answer still valid today.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few steps you will need if you follow Piyush Khandelwal answer above:

First of all...you need to get your phone into `developer mode`
To do that...Go into `Settings`
Scroll to the bottom to `About Phone`
Find the `Build Number` and tap it seven times.
*(this enables the developer options in settings)*

**Now you will have `Developer options` in `Setting`**

Go into `Developer options` and check `USB debugging`..

Now plug your phone into your PC...
You will be presented with a `Connect to PC` dialogue Box.
Select the `Install Driver` radio button
Check the `Enable USB debugging` check box.

Now start Visual Studio and your phone should be an emulator option.

Answer (score 5):

- Just set the solution to release mode.
- Right Click your Android Main Project -> Export Android Package(.apk)
- Go to the bin\release Folder, you could find your app in apk format.  Use application with Signed extension(Signed.apk)
- Install the apk on your device.